# Does grappling speed depend on the class?

Tags: team-fortress-2, team-fortress-2-beta

In the new Mannpower update, we're given grapple hooks, which allow the player to grapple onto almost any surface in the map. However, does the speed at which the player grapples from one place to another depend on the class used? e.g. Do Scouts "grapple swing " faster than Heavies, or is it the same speed for all classes?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done any solid testing, but it appears that grappling speed is the same regardless of class.

**However**, the Agility powerup doubles your grapple speed.  Too bad only one player can have the powerup at a time.